# Android ListView with received & sent SMS

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, sms

I am developing an android SMS app. I have become successful in sending and receiving SMS.
Now i want to show received & sent SMS in a single listView in alternate fashion i.e as in Android native messenger.Can anyone give me idea how to show both sent and received data via single ListView. Is ListView with even and odd rows is feasible for it.???
Any helpful tutorial, code snippet will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to merge the dataset for texts sent to a particular number with the data set for texts received from that number then sort it all by the time/date they were sent. In the adapter's getView, you can check to see who the text was sent by and inflate a view accordingly.

Comment: yeah , but how to do so ?? Currently i am saving SMS in SQlite db.